# How to use master/slave mysql in play framework

Tags: mysql, playframework

My application is getting a lot of database calls hence I need to start using a distributed master/slave mysql database but I'm having problems configuring play framework!

so my first question is that if it is actually possible to configure hibernate and jpa with play framework to take advantage of replication driver

if, it is not possible, is there any other technique to use a distributed mysql schema with play

this is my configuration:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql:replication://[master ip]:3306,[slave ip]:3306/<dbname>autoReconnectForPools=true&roundRobinLoadBalance=true&loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=5000&loadBalanceStrategy=random

db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver  
db.user=<dbusername>
db.pass=<dbpassword>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user724051's answer which was previously inserted into someone else's answer:

Multiple db is not the solution, since the app is not really using different databases. I found the problem with my configuration file, apparently you have to explicitly tell hibernate what dialect it needs to use so, this is the way to configure it (although, to this point i am suspicious if it really sends reads to slave and writes to master yet - my cpu and memory utilization on the master is still suspiciously high!)

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://[master ip]:3306,[slave1 ip]:3306/<dbname>   
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver
db.user=<db username>
db.pass=<db password>
jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [MultiDB](http://www.playframework.org/modules/multidb) module. Its description sounds like what you are after.

> Multiple Database module for the Play! framework. This module allows
>   you to scale your Play! apps to multiple databases with a common
>   schema.

Comment: @user724051, please add your new text as a new answer, rather than drastically amending Codemwnci's answer -- while we're all allowed to edit anything on the site, please don't amend answers beyond their initial "intent". (Yes, it is a gray line, but in this case your edit completely repudiates the original intent of Codemwnci's answer.) Some of your new text might be best used as a comment to this answer, some might be best used as a new answer outright. For example: I'm still not sure if you are still fighting this problem. Thanks!